# How can node.js server get(read) "request header" in POST method?

Tags: node.js, server, header

I made http server on node.js as below.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var method = req.method;
  switch(method)
  {
    case 'POST':      
      var header1 = req.headers['1'];
      console.log('header1 : '+ header1);
      break;
  }
}).listen(port, function(){  
});
```

I request to server using postMan with header as below.

```
key : value
1   : 1
```

but the console result was below.

```
header1 : undefined
```

How can get as below?

```
header1 : 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a header with the name "1"? Use `req.headers['header1'];` instead. That are absolutely basics.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it. How can I get the value of header '1' instead of 'undefined'

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) incl. your postman request.

Answer (score 0):

It works well.

Use lower-case when indexing header key!

> *header[**'main-id'**]*

The header requested is below.

```
'Main-ID' : Solar
'Sub-ID'  : Jupiter
```

working code is below.

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var method = req.method;
  var header = req.headers;
  var mainID = header['main-id'];
  var subID = header['sub-id'];
  switch(method)
  {
    case 'POST':
      console.log('header : \n');
      console.log(header);
      console.log('mainID : '+ mainID);
      console.log('subID  : '+ subID);
      break;
  }
}).listen(port, function(){
  console.log(`Service server running ${port}!`);
});
```

console is below

```
header :
{
   'main-id': 'Solar',
   'sub-id': 'Jupiter',
   'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.2',
   ...
 }
 mainID : Solar
 subID  : Jupiter
```

Thanks.

Comment: When using "express" module, it works for case-sensitive, `req.header('Main-ID');`. But, when not using "express", how can do for case-sensitive?